# Split a string on a capital letter or numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I was trying to make a pipe in typescript that would split a PascalCase string, but it would be nice if this would also split on digits as well. I would also like it to split on consecutive capital letters.  I have this pipe, which works great, except it only works in Chrome and not Firefox, evidently only Chrome supports look backs.  How can accomplish this without look backs?

```
transform(value: string): string {
        let extracted = '';
        if (!value) {
            return extracted;
        }

        const regExSplit = value
            .split(new RegExp('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])'));
        for (let i = 0; i < regExSplit.length; i++) {
            if (i !== regExSplit.length - 1) {
                extracted += `${regExSplit[i]} `;
            } else {
                extracted += regExSplit[i];
            }
        }

        return extracted;
    }
```

So for example a string `ANet15Amount` should be transformed into `A Net 15 Amount`. This regex above also would split a camelCase string, but that's not necessary to consider.

Comment: `.replace(/([A-Z]|\d+)/g, " $1").trim();`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir `(?!^)([A-Z]|\d+)` avoids first space and doesn't need trim.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about [matching](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) by a more basic pattern [like this](https://regex101.com/r/Y1bBJn/2) and [joining](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with space.

```js
let str = `ANet15Amount`;

let camel = str.match(/[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z]?[a-z]+|\d+/g).join(' ');

console.log(camel);
```

First I thought of simply `[A-Z][a-z]*|\d+` but this would break eg `ABCDefg123` into `A B C Defg 123` which would be different working to your current function, that transforms to `ABC Defg 123`.

There is still a little difference. Yours transforms `A1B2` to `A 1B 2` and this one to `A 1 B 2` where I think this one would be more accurate, wouldn't it.

Comment: Brilliant, passed all my test cases.  I agree, yours is more accurate.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @develmatik Glad it works as desired, I just read about the differences of Camel to [PascalCase](http://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase) :)

Answer (score 6):

Just replace any uppercase letter `[A-Z]` or any sequence of digits `\d+` with a space plus what we just matched `" $1"`. We skip the first letter so that no space will be added at the begining of the resulting string by adding a negative lookahead on the start of the string `(?!^)`:

```
// ...

return value.replace(/(?!^)([A-Z]|\d+)/g, " $1");
```

**Example:**

```js
let value = "ANet15Amount";

let result = value.replace(/(?!^)([A-Z]|\d+)/g, " $1");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `[A-Z]?[a-z]+|[A-Z]|[0-9]+`

- 0 or 1 uppercase letter directly followed by 1 or more lowercase letters
- or 1 uppercase letter
- or 1 or more digits

Test in generator:
https://regex101.com/r/uBO0P5/1

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on the string's conventions which may increase the complexity

```js
// here 'TIMES' & 'with' are seperated (example 2)
const str = 'SplittingStringsIsFunTimesA100000aaaTIMESwithFollowUp';

// here 'TIMES' & 'With' are seperated (exmpaple 3)
const str2 = 'SplittingStringsIsFunTimesA100000aaaTIMESWithCAPITAL5FollowUp';


// 1. USING REGEX - MATCH
console.log(
  '1. USING REGEX:\n',
  str
  .match(/(\d+|[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]*)/g)
  .join(' ')
);


// 2. USING REGEX - MATCH (KEEP ALL CAPITAL CHARS)
console.log(
  '2. USING REGEX (GROUP ALL):\n',
  str
  .match(/(\d+|[a-z]+|([A-Z]([A-Z]+|[a-z]*)))/g)
  .join(' ')
);

// 3. USING REGEX - MATCH (KEEP CAPITAL CHARS BUT LAST)
console.log(
  '3. USING REGEX (GROUP BUT LAST):\n',
  str2
  .match(/(\d+|[a-z]+|([A-Z]([a-z]+|([A-Z]+(?![a-z]))?)))/g)
  .join(' ')
);


// 4. USING SPLIT - FILTER
console.log(
  '4. USING SPLIT:\n',
  str2
  .split(/(\d+|[A-Z][a-z]*)/)
  .filter(v => v !== '')
  .join(' ')
);
```